# Continous Form - Image control click event to recognise current record

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have a subform that looks like this that I'm wanting to use as a task list:

[image]

The task is marked as completed in the record using a Yes/No field called ***TaskStatus***; this is shown as the checkbox control to the right in the above screenshot.

Rather than use this checkbox though, I'd like to do something a bit more fancy-pants and have the user click the image control called ***imgTaskIcon*** shown as the red flag on the left, which will both mark the ***TaskStatus*** field for the record appropriately and toggle its own image to that of either a red flag (not completed) or a green tick (completed).

At the moment, I have the control source of ***imgTaskIcon*** set to look at another (hidden) field in the record that is storing the path to the appropriate completed/not completed image.

I've then got this code running on ***imgTaskIcon*** click event, which essentially toggles ***TaskStatus*** from yes (-1) to no (0):

```vb
Private Sub imgTaskIcon_Click()

    If _
        Me.TaskStatus = -1 _
    Then
        Me.TaskStatus = 0
    Else
        Me.TaskStatus = -1
    End If

    toggleTaskStatusIcon

End Sub
```

And then `toggleTaskStatusIcon`, which sets the correct image path for the record:

```vb
Public Sub toggleTaskStatusIcon()

    If _
        Me.TaskStatus = -1 _
    Then
        Me.TaskStatusIcon = "P:\myPath\CompletedIcon.png"
    Else
        Me.TaskStatusIcon = "P:\myPath\NotCompletedIcon.png"
    End If

End Sub
```

This works fine when toggling the first record:

[image]

However, clicking the image on the second record, just toggles the first record again:

[image]

By first clicking in to some other control in the record, I can then click the image control and the toggle works on the appropriate record. So it seems that an image control won't change the current record to its own record when it is clicked.

Is there a way to get an image control to be less ambivalent about where it lives?

Comment: the known trick was to use a transparent button on top of the image. or use button with image.

Comment: another irrelevant point: you can upload the picture into your database picture collection and share it throughout your application without reading from disk. this can save hardlinking

Comment: thanks @krishKM, after some better searching I found the same solution: http://www.devhut.net/2013/10/27/ms-access-image-control-on-click-event-in-continuous-form-not-returning-the-proper-recordprimary-key/ Thanks for the picture collection tip too :)